# power BI Vega Lite mark color lighter

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite

I have the following example:
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/circle_github_punchcard.html

I need this to include color scaling.

For this I have tried some options which resulted in the following:
[editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AAk2mgF5zMSQYICeAAihyoSTHFlO4yuzCTrMEG-ScbCBg2AHcbZRoAMyi4dRdMfyscNRs2KIiaDTgdYxpZMiDHQTVKRRUnFFRQYgsGNTQAbVAqkABBcqY0ACYABj6lKDQARmGlZTQAZgBfBRa0ds6e-t7BtAAWXspu8anZ+fQOpS7UPu6xkCHUTe3d0-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)

You can see the slight difference in color. How can I make it a consistent color?

Comment: Can you clarify what  your end result should look like? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: yes, what I would like to archive is to have the same colours as in the legend, but when I have only one entry. Now what is happening is that I get closer to that closer when I add more data points for that specific point.

Comment: Arjen, did the answer solve the solution? If so please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because your dataset as duplicate 2022 values for C.

Simply add the **opacity** setting directly within the encoding section:

```
"encoding": {
    "opacity": {"value": 1},
```